# Excel: Communicating user in-put to another module

Tags: database, vba, excel, input

I have a macro that populates a listbox that tells me all of the workbook names that are currently open on my computer that incorporates a double-click event to select the name of the workbook that I am hoping to activate to run other procedures.  I have tried several methods to get the selection from the listbox to be recalled within my second procedure, but I don't seem to be wording my code correctly and I keep getting errors. Any advice?

What I am working with currently:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Dim BName As Long

For BName = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
If Me.ListBox1.Selected(BName) Then
    Me.ListBox1.Selected(BName) = True
    With Me.ListBox1.Selected(NName)
    Call Q
    End If

Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    With Me.ListBox1
        For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
        .AddItem wkb.Name
    Next wkb
End With
End Sub
```

Sub Q:

```
Public Sub Q()

Dim BName As Object

With ListBox1.Selected(BName).Value

Workbooks(BName).Activate
With Active.Workbooks
.Worksheets("MYDATA").Range("D2:D103").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("MARCH1158(1).xlsm").Worksheets("FORMULAS").Select
Range("G2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Interface").Select
Sheets("FORMULAS").Select
ListBox1.Value.Select
Range("E2:E103").Select
Range("E103").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
Range("E2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Interface").Select
Sheets("FORMULAS").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
End With
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I'd say your best bet is to create procedure `Q` to take a parameter, with the parameter being set to the selected value in the listbox. Since we don't have the code for Q, I've set up a relatively simplified procedure to get you started.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim BName As Long

    For BName = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(BName) Then
            Q (Me.ListBox1.List(BName))
        End If
    Next BName

    Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.ListBox1
        .AddItem "Hello"
        .AddItem "Goodbye"
        .AddItem "Saluations"
    End With
End Sub

Sub Q(strSelection As String)
       Workbooks(strSelection).Activate
       ' Enter the rest of the code here     
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @user3561813! My current Q sub::
Dim BName As Object

    WB(BName).Activate
    W/ Active.Workbooks
    .WS("MYDATA").Range("D2:D103").Select
    Selection.Copy
    WB("Decisions").WS("A1").Select
Range("G2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("A1").Select
ListBox1.Value.Select
    Range("E2:E103").Select
    Range("E103").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("B2").Select
    Sheets("A1").Select
    End With
End With
End Sub

Comment: will this same code apply if I use the the Sub Q (strSelection As String) and then just incorporate that with my existing Q?  I have tried several different methods for "trapping" the selection value and communicating it to the Q sub (with public functions, etc) but they all returned object errors.

Comment: @user3794203 Is it possible to add the code for `Sub Q` as an edit to your original post. It is difficult to read code in the comments section. Also, please mention what you want code `Q` to do, and how the `listbox` selection relates. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry!  Just re-edited so it is more legible now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user3794203 A few points to mention: (1) The logic behind your code is syntactically wrong. `ListBox1.Selected(Bname).Value` will return an error. The `.Selected(int)` property returns True/False based on whether the item is selected. To access the value at that index, you'd use 'Listbox1.List(BName)`. With that said, if you modify your `Q` code as I've described above, with the code taking a parameter, you can reference your workbooks based on the parameter names. I'm going to edit my code above so you can see how it would look.